# NPM command works with CMD but it isn't working with BASH, any ideas?

Tags: node.js, bash, express

I'm following a MERN project tutorial to create a simple TODO app.
Working with the bash terminal everything was going smoothly setting the server with Express, I have a very simple server file such as:

```
const express = require ('express');

const app =express();

//TODO: configuration
app.get("/todos", (req, res) =>{
   res.send("ça marche, on va voir !")
})


app.listen(8080)
```

Then trying to set the package.json script to :

`"scripts": { "start": "nodemon src/index.js"   },`

anytime I hit `npm run start` I get the following error on the bash terminal :

```
>server@1.0.0 start
>nodemon src/index.js 
node' is not recognized as an internal or an external command, operable program...
```

BUT when I tried with CMD terminal everything went fine.
I checked my Node version with bash and I get a normal answer...
I can keep working with CMD and it's OK but I kind of want to figure it out why it is I'm getting a problem with one terminal, it's very annoying not to know where the problem comes from.

I really appreciate all your comments and possible answers

I tried the basic methods like `node -v` to check if my bash terminal was answering to that and it's  did

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are doing, but I can tell you this is not a bash error:

```
... is not recognized as an internal or an external command...
```

This is a CMD error that you would never see in an actual Linux environment.  So, if I had to guess, you are running this in WSL which can *sort of* call into Windows programs.  So (spitballing here) you are running Windows version of `npm` in bash, and it looks like npm spawned a CMD shell with a slightly different environment than it would have in normal CMD.

If you install `npm` and `nodejs` on WSL itself, it should work as expected.  As most popular WSL distributions are Debian based, you can do this with `apt`:

```
sudo apt install npm nodejs
```

**Update**

Likely, it is an issue with the environment variables.  More specifically, if it cannot find a program, it is an issue with the `%PATH%` variable.  This variable is responsible for providing a list of search paths for programs.  The issue is the bash terminal is designed to run in a Linux environment.  An emulated Linux environment can call into Windows programs, but there are limitations, and this appears to be one of them.

That specific error you are getting *is* an error you only see in the *Windows* command prompt.  To see for yourself, open `cmd.exe`, and type in some gibberish and hit ENTER.  It will give you that exact same error.  In Linux, that error would take the form: "-bash: shnt: command not found".

Given that information, we can make an educated guess on what `npm` is doing.  `npm.exe` doesn't actually care how it got ran.  What it does know is that it is a Windows program, and if it wants to run a shell, it will run `cmd.exe`.  We can actually verify this by looking at their own [docs](https://github.com/npm/cli/blob/latest/docs/lib/content/commands/npm-run-script.md).  So `npm` actually spawns a shell just for `npm run ...`.  Here is where the issue lies.  The chain of commands here is:

```
bash -> npm -> cmd.exe
```

And somewhere in there the `PATH` variable gets lost in translation.  My guess is `cmd.exe` inherits the Linux `$PATH`, not the Windows `%PATH%`, so it cannot find `node.exe`.

As far as a solution goes, it seems you must actually run a Linux version of `npm`.  There are just too many quirks in this case to run the Windows version out of an emulated Linux environment.

**More info on PATH**

`%PATH%` is a *semi-colon* delimited list that might look like this:

```
C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;...
```

To see what yours actually is, you can type `echo %PATH%` in CMD.

The Linux `$PATH` variable is a *colon* delimited list of paths.  These normally include stuff like `/bin` and `/usr/bin`. The *emulated* Linux environment translates `%PATH%` into the Linux equivalent `$PATH`, so that it can find standard Windows programs to run.  So it will sort of have both `PATH` variables combined into something like:

```
/bin:/usr/bin:/mnt/c/WINDOWS:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32:/mnt/c/Program Files/nodejs:...
```

Note that the Windows paths now start with `/mnt/c/` instead of `C:\`. To see what yours actually is, you can type `echo $PATH` in bash.  Since programs "inherit" the environment of their parent process (bash in this case), it's reasonable that `npm.exe` is running with the Linux `$PATH`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! In deed I am working on Windows and running Windows version of npm, and as I said before, I am not having any trouble working with the CMD but I just wanted to know why the bash terminal is throwing an error that the CMD is not throwing, If I got it right it's because the work environment?

Comment: @NevidRahal Yes. See the update in the answer.